# How do I cause my toilet to drip to prevent pipes from freezing?

Tags: plumbing, freezing, copper-pipe

I have a toilet whose supply pipe is prone to freezing, and I would like to continuously run a small amount of water through it. Similar to how you can set a tap to dripping to prevent freezing. Ideally I don't want to destroy the flapper, but I can do that if it's necessary.

Unfortunately insulation and heat tape is not an option for this pipe (or rather, we have already tried). It runs through an uninsulated concrete slab with no clearance, which is where the pipe has frozen in the past, so this is the last try before we have to try more substantial fixes.

Comment: There are ways to make the flapper leak, but then you're wasting water - and if it gets *really* cold, then the leak might be insufficient, and you'll wind up with a frozen pipe anyway. The proper way to fix this is to put in a new water pipe, and make sure it doesn't go through any unheated spaces.

Comment: Hilarious, I have to scrape calcium off my flappers every few months to STOP them from leaking!

Comment: @MikeBaranczak   Should make this into an answer, since it is the right/proper way to deal with the problem.

Comment: @jay613  Probably the reason smart people get water softeners.

Comment: I would tape or weight down the flush arm or float to keep it "on", then put something under the flapper, like a spoon to keep it from sealing. It will then run constantly, no danger of stopping. Then you crank down the little valve on the fill behind the toilet until there's just the trickle of water you want/need. This is 100% reversible and there's no annoying intermittent noise, just a low level white noise that's easier to tune out.

Comment: Are you where there is the odd cold spell or is this a winter long thing?  If winter long then moving the pipes is the only answer.  My answer and the other answer is for places like Texas that might get cold for a few days.

Comment: do not put anything under the flapper, it will end up in your toilet and might clog it –

Comment: adjusting the fill valve would work

Comment: A few thoughts:  Is this your regular home or a vacation home?  If a vacation home, I'd turn  off the water and blow out the pipes with a compressor.  If your regular home, it must get pretty damn cold to freeze pipes in a slab on grade! Next:  I obviously don't know your plumbing, but don't ignore the possibility of your **DRAIN LINE** freezing.  It would make make a BIG MESS, if it froze with an intentionally dripping toilet feeding it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the fill valve instead of the flapper, by adjusting the water level just slightly too high such that water is running down the overflow tube. This will cause the valve to stay open just a bit, trying to fill.

The "flapper" method will provide intermittent water flow; the "fill valve" method will cause constant flow. Both are going to cost you: either your water bill goes up, or your electric bill goes up if pumping from a well.

Answer (score 2):

Will need to place something so the flapper leaks.

Something like a penny, toothpick place between the flapper and the tank hole.

Turn off the shut off valve, drain the tank and dry/clean. Place a small dab of silicon under the object to use and let set for a day.

Tank should have a slow leak and drain, and should fill back up repeatably every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Bend up or adjust up the float until it fills up and goes into the overflow. Consider a heating tape wrap, they only come on when the pipe is under a certain temp. Mine are set at 42f about 30 bucks.

Answer (score 0):

Tie a small string to the lever that lifts the flapper. Make it long enough to get sucked in under flapper when you flush. If you need it to leak more, tie a knot in string where flapper will close on it. No drying out tank or reaching into cold water. When you don’t need toilet to run, drape string onto mechanism so it won’t get sucked in.